# Dynamically adding div on button click and changing Id of each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and just wanted to add new clones on a button click:

I wrote this much code:

```
<div class="main" id="container">
    <div class="item">
        items
    </div>
</div>
<button id="button">
    Click me
</button>

<script>
  $("#button").click(function () {

  });
</script>
```

Exactly what I am looking for is a clone, but ids should be different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding div dynamically using button click in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812786/adding-div-dynamically-using-button-click-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: There are heaps of these questions, please actually look them up

Comment: Please do a basic research before you post any questions here.

Comment: I'am already searched for this problem in stackoverflow not found .

Comment: the link you posted have some similarity but i'am looking for something more.. anyway thank you for your guids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try  this :-**

```
 $("#button").click(function () {
    var clone = $("#container").find(".item").last().clone();
     clone.attr("id","newId");
     $("#container").append(clone);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#button").click(function () {
  $('.item').append('<div>new div</div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" id="container">
<div class="item">
items
</div>
</div>
<button id="button">
Click me
</button>
```

hope it will help